# Do input features need to be in a distribution?

Tags: machine-learning, distributions, svm, libsvm

I am currently starting my machine learning project on binary classification and I have been taught that input data features should be in a distribution (although the distribution type itself need not to be determined), which arises questions to me

1. Is it true?
2. If it is true, why does the input features have to be in a distribution
3. (The most important one): If it is true, how can I determine if an input feature is in a distribution or not, are there any ways or algorithm to determine this?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is a strange remark in that literally everything can be thought of as coming from some sort of distribution. The distribution in question might be some sort of weird multimodal, long-tailed fiasco without a name, but if you're not worried about identifying it, then who cares?

However, perhaps you were being encouraged to think about whether features were continuous vs. discrete? These are both broad categories of distributions and some algorithms (and implementations) treat them differently. A discrete feature takes on a value from some pre-determined (often small) set of possible values, like a person's gender, language, or employment status. A continuous feature, however, varies smoothly, at least over some range; Height or weight might be a good examples. (Be aware that we don't always follow the precise definition--height, rounded to the nearest cm, is mathematically discrete but is can sometimes be treated as continuous in practice).

You would usually know whether a feature is continuous or discrete from a description of the data set. I suppose you could also look at the number of unique values--discrete variables are almost always coded as integers.

Comment: Thank you, I have some more questions
If that's so, how should I treat discrete and continuous data, do I scale them linearly into [-1,1] or do I standardize them (even if they are not distributed normally?)